# How to add two to any number passed through it (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby

I am doing the Ruby Monk tutorial and got stuck on a problem. Here it is:

"Write a method called add_two that adds 2 to any number passed to it and returns the result. Yes, please feel free to experiment using next in addition to the more obvious route of simply adding the integer 2 to the incoming number."

I started with:

```
def add_two(number)
 number + number
end
```

But i am not sure how to account for negative numbers

Any help would be great!

Comment: They want you to add the number 2 to a number not number + number though?

Comment: You don't even know the difference between addition of two and multiplication by two? That's elementary school math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what they are asking you to do is to use `next` which is a method of the Integer class.

[Ruby API - Integer#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-next)

It should look something like this

```
def add_two(number)     
  number.next.next
end
```

Comment: More relevantly, it's also a method of Integer. That's the method you're actually using here.

Comment: @Chuck I forgot what I was writing :D

Answer (score 1):

If I pass you 6, you give me back 8. That is what the function is supposed to do.

You can find information about `next` in [`Integer Class API`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-next).

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the challenge. It was not "add two *of* any number" — it was "add two *to* any number". So the "obvious" answer is

```
def add_two(number)
  number + 2
end
```

This will work just fine with negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks man, I just ran this one and it works too!!